# SQL Server Management Studio STR() function centers column data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms, sql-function

I believe this to be more of a cosmetic issue and caused by SQL Server Management Studio but does anybody know why my column data is offset when I convert a `float` to a `nvarchar` using the `STR()` function? Is this a cosmetic bug in SQL Server Management Studio or actually something meaningful that is affecting my data?

The column in question is the 3rd column over, as you can see there are multiple 1's that seem to be centered in relation to the larger 10 digit numbers.

[image: Screenshot of my query results]

Comment: I think SSMS right justifies numbers but centers (or perhaps sometimes left justifies) strings.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Could it be the case that an entire textual column with only numerical data in it would be the centered type offset I'm seeing? Kind of a mixture of the 2 cases you noted?

Comment: The column is not center aligned. The str function returns CHAR data, not varchar. The 1's you see are padded to the left. The paddings are taking lesser space and hence it seems to be aligned this way. See here" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189527.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's padding with spaces.

Where VALUE = 1 (float), I get:

```
len(str(VALUE)) = 10
ascii(str(VALUE)) = 32
ascii(right(str(VALUE),9)) = 32
etc...
```

char(32) = space

According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms189527(v=sql.110).aspx):

> A short float_expression is right-justified in the specified length, and a long float_expression is truncated to the specified number of decimal places. For example, STR(12,10) yields the result of 12. This is right-justified in the result set.

Seems that "right-justification" in this context means exactly padding a short value with spaces, so that the 'number-as-string' component is at the far end of the string.  If this isn't want you want, then you probably want a different function.